# BitmapImage and Bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, bitmapimage

Sorry to ask a question like that but I can't found a good answer :/

What is the difference between BitmapImage and Bitmap?

I want to work with TIFF image with any one of them I have to work. I found some tutorial that works with BitmapImage and another that works with Bitmap.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) is a specialized [BitmapSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx) that is optimized for loading images using Extensible Application Markup Language (XAML).

[System.Drawing.Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) is a encapsulates a GDI+ bitmap which consists of the pixel data for a graphics image and its attributes.

The first is used with WPF/Silverlight (XAML), the second is used with Windows Forms (WinForms).

Comment: System.Drawing.Bitmap is not specific to winforms, it can just as easily be used in asp.net, a WCF service, a windows service etc.

Comment: But it's generally used in WinForms. Specially in the context of his question. The MSDN links should clarify the rest.

Comment: Sorry but i think it is misleading, it is used for manipulating bitmap images, and is unrelated to winforms, hence the System.Drawing namespace

Comment: I disagree. With Silverlight/WPF you would use WriteableBitmap for manipulating bitmap images. So I find System.Drawing to be technology specific.

Comment: Bitmap only encapsulates GDI+ native object. GDI+ is not specific to WinForms.
BitmapSource uses completely new set of APIs

Answer (score 1):

Bitmap is a general purpose class in System.Drawing which can be used to manipulate images.
Whereas the BitmapImage class is more geared toward use in the XAML / WPF world.