# C# Fast frame image loading from video file

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, frame, seek

I'm trying to implement a VirtualDub-like video editor into my C# app that can display any frame from a video file (h264 is the main focus).

I've already implemented something with FFMPEG from this post:
[Get thumbnail image of video file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702031/get-thumbnail-image-of-video-file-in-c-sharp)

but it's too slow. I'd like to just access the frame image directly from the video without needing to write an image file to disk.

Is there a way to achieve this kind of frame-accurate seeking in C#?

Comment: There are native APIs for video files: Media Foundation, DirectShow. They can work much faster, compared to the method you are referring to. It is not FFmpeg slow, of course, it is command line interop which is killing everything here.

Comment: @Dili, What did you end up doing? I'm having a similar problem, and DirectShow.net is not getting me much further, especially when trying to play various file formats.