# How can use Video Converter for .NET (C#) or other FFMpeg wrapper To create Video Thumbnail in Asp MVc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, video, ffmpeg

I want to create video thumbnails on my sites by using FFMpeg wrapper like Video Converter for .NET (C#) I am saving my video files in mp4 and wmv locally in video folder.if somebody know other wrapper please let me know and how can I use this

```
(new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter()).GetVideoThumbnail(tmpFile, outputJpegStream);
```

Regards

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702031/get-thumbnail-image-of-video-file-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

User follow code:

`var ffmpeg = new FFMpegConverter();
ffmpeg.GetVideoThumbnail(path, ThumbnailPath, second);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.