# create thumbnail from video URL in C#

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, video-thumbnails

I want to generate thumbnail from a video URL in C#. I have searched a lot to find a neat way but no success. I have used `Nreco` and `MediaToolKit` but none of them extract thumbnail image. using ffmpeg also has mumbo jumbos which didn't worked!

using NReco:

```
var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
string thumbnailJPEGpath = "http://localhost:81882/content/hashem.jpeg";
ffMpeg.GetVideoThumbnail(videoUrl,thumbnailJPEGpath);
```

using ffmpeg:

```
try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process ffmpeg;

            string video;
            string thumb;

            video = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Movies/bye.mp4");
            thumb = Server.MapPath("~/Content/frame.jpg");

            ffmpeg = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

            ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = " -i " + video + " -ss 00:00:07 -vframes 1 -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg " + thumb;
            ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Content/ffmpeg.exe");
            ffmpeg.Start();
            ffmpeg.WaitForExit();
            ffmpeg.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

to consider video files are not local and I have only a direct link to the file:
e.g.:`http://phytonord.com/Film-Series/hana/26.mp4`

does anyone has any solution? any sample code that works?

Comment: possible duplicate of [get thumbnail image of video file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702031/get-thumbnail-image-of-video-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: tested both but not working. would you mind to test with video link provided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using NReco to Create Video Thumbnail:

I found my problem:

1: I have not used Server.MapPath. I had just entered relativePath.

2: it is not necessary the Video file be *local* it can be hosted someWhere else.
NReco just download the desired portion of video then extract the Thumbnail.
your Video file should be in localHost directory of your local server. I mean if your site is under development and video file is in your local Computer folder **it WON'T Work** because NReco requires byte range support in HTTP response Header file.

**Unacceptable Link**: "http://localhost:81882/content/AVSEQ01.mp4"

so for my local test, I have moved my video file to Local IIS directory :  `‪C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AVSEQ01.mp4`

```
//sample remote video file
//string videoUrl = "http://phytonord.com/Film-Series/peik%20sahar/1.mp4";

 //local video file
string localVideoFile = "http://localhost/AVSEQ01.mp4"
var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
string thumbnailJPEGpath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/videoThumb.jpg");
ffMpeg.GetVideoThumbnail(videoUrl, thumbnailJPEGpath);
```

Comment: I thought I need to download the file to a local path first. Turns out I can simply use the url. Thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: The command your provided will create a single thumbnail image, what about creating multiple images after every second of the total video length. Currently, we are using the below command to create a sprite image. **Step1 -->** `ffmpeg -i corpfilm.mp4 -s 280x150 -vf fps=1 thumb/img%03d.jpg` **Step 2-->** `magick montage *.jpg 160x90 -geometry +0+0 overview.jpg` from command prompt. How do we achieve it through C#? Plz guide.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the question is answered But not written clearly, So here is my answer:
First download the [DLL](http://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx)

```
ffMpeg.GetVideoThumbnail(inputFile,outputFile, frameTime);
// Summary:
    //     Extract video frame from local video file at specified position
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   inputFile:
    //     path to local video file
    //
    //   outputFile:
    //     path to thumbnail jpeg file
    //
    //   frameTime:
    //     video position (in seconds)
```

this is how I did in my project

```
            var thumbNailMovieImage = PHYSICAL_PATH_UPLOAD_FILE + "/" + folder + "/thumb_" + filenameWithoutExtn + ".jpg";
            var ffMpeg = new FFMpegConverter();
            ffMpeg.GetVideoThumbnail(path, thumbNailMovieImage, 1);
```

Now run this code and check the location your thumbnail file is created

Comment: Is any way to  get return Image from actual video link?

Comment: bcoz I am using the same video converter. And I don't want to return image into Local folder..I want doing some updates from the return Image(fromvideo file/url).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, if some one looking for creating multiple thumb image extracting for sprite image creation using ffmpeg or NReco library.

**Using Command line** --> ffmpeg -i corpfilm.mp4 -s 280x150 -vf fps=1 thumb/img%03d.jpg

Under the hood **NReco.VideoConverter** executes ffmpeg with System.Diagnostics.Process API; this means that you can run any command that is possible in the command line.

For this concrete command VideoConverter's API equivalent:

```
var ffmpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
ffmpeg.ConvertMedia(
  "corpfilm.mp4", null,
  " thumb/img%03d.jpg", null,
  new ConvertSettings() {
    CustomOutputArgs = " -s 280x150 -vf fps=1 "
  });
```