# Extracting a Thumbnail from a video in a MemoryStream C# .Net Framework 4.6.2

Tags: c#, video, thumbnails, filestream, snapshot

I'm searching for a package able to extract one image at a given time of a video stored in a C# MemoryStream (.Net Framework 4.6.2) (in memory, not on disk). I have found a lot of wrapper for FFmpeg (I've tried Xabe.FFmpeg, MediaToolkit, NReco.VideoConverter, which all work fine) but I could not find any handling a file in memory. So i'd like to know if someone already did this before I start making my own wrapper, which does not look easy from my standpoint. Or if You know of an open source wrapper that I could use / modify. Thank you.

To add some precisions, I'm working on a midleware on which Videos are uploaded to then be stored by a third party (I don't know where the files are stored) and I'd like to extract a Thumnail from the video (the image at 10 seconds of a video). I stay at your disposal if you need any details.

I can't use any command line tool or the libraries that I tried because I can't use the disk, it has to be in memory.

Comment: Hi, did you consider saving the video file to the disk, processing it to extract the thumbnail and then delete it ? I assume using one of the libraries you mentioned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get thumbnail image of video file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702031/get-thumbnail-image-of-video-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I can't have a direct access to the disk, and it is not a duplicate, the objective is to be able to do basicaly  the same thing but with the file in memory

Comment: Why can't you use the disk?

Comment: I do not have permissions

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I'm facing a similar one trying to extract a thumbnail from a video uploaded to an Azure Api

Comment: @MatiasMasso and Pierre Alymat did you get your answer? I have a streams for super large files that I don't want to save to disk, and just want to get video length and thumbnails from using memory stream.