# How can I get a thumbnail from a video that a user has uploaded to mySQL database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a video sharing website where people can upload their own videos and I want the most recent uploads to be shown on the index page, but not as videos but thumbnails, so that when you click on the thumbnail you get to the video page. You guys all know how youtube's index looks/works - that's what I'm trying to simulate.

I read about ffmpeg but it seems to me it would only work if you have ffmpeg installed on your computer. I want this to be an automated process though without the user having to first install something on their pc.
Is there a way I can code this? Or do i have to use some kind of framework or CMS? Could this problem be solved by simply getting ffmpeg hosting (example)?
If there is no manual way to do this in c#, is there way using c# asp.net?

Fyi, my website is written in c# and i use image to display the thumbnail of the video .
Please note that I want to get a thumbnail from a video that's been uploaded on MYSQL database and not a youtube or vimeo thumbnail.

Comment: Surely you only need ffmpeg installed on your server, as you will create a thumbnail from the video on your server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get thumbnail image of video file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702031/get-thumbnail-image-of-video-file-in-c-sharp)