# Generate/Fetch thumbnail from video files for official use without using FFMPEG in c# for commercial purpose

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, thumbnails, video-processing

I'm creating the file manager in .NET core using c# and devexpress control filemanager.
for this I want to generate thumbnails for video files but it is for commercial purpose so I  cant use FFMPEG for the same.
Any help will be appreciated.

I tried MediaToolkit  but it didn't worked in .Net Core.
I have checked the solutions like

1. [NReco](https://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx)
2. [MediaToolkit.NetCore](https://github.com/mtebenev/MediaToolkit.NetCore)
3. ShellFile
4. Xabe.FFmpeg

But many from this above solutions requires FFMPEG.exe which I cant use commercial purpose.

Comment: Find out how to play a video using C# and from there just screenshot the frames you need (_eg:_ you can [try using MediaElement](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/take-screen-shot-from-media-element-in-wpf/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ShellFile` is available, but it does not seem to support .net 5 and .net6 versions. If you use version 3.1, you can try this.

You need to install two Nuget packages: `Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Shell` and `System.Drawing.Common`. Here you need to pay attention to the choice of `Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Shell`:

[image]

Test Code:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ShellFile shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath("file path\\filename");
    Bitmap bitmap = shellFile.Thumbnail.Bitmap;
    bitmap.Save("File output path\\filename", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    return View();
}
```

For example, I output it to the Models folder:

[image]

For more details, you can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60425444/18789859).